# How to click the first item from first my class into my component using protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, css-selectors, protractor

I need to click at the  button from this component, but I don't know how to do this.

I need to follow this path:

How can I do this? is xpath my only alternative?
I think I can use the css locator but I don't know how to write the 
relative path.

app-lista-convites-lote 
card card-convite ng-star-inserted
btn btn-danger btn-no-text
zmdi zmdi-delete

**HTML**

```
   <app-lista-convites-lote _ngcontent-c13="" _nghost-c18="">
        <div _ngcontent-c18="" class="card card-convite ng-star-inserted">
            <div _ngcontent-c18="" class="kebab kebab-convite">
                <button _ngcontent-c18="" class="btn btn-danger btn-no-text" title="Remover convite" type="button">
                    <i _ngcontent-c18="" class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how specific you need to be which depends on the html of your entire page. All of these examples select the same element, but with different levels on specificity using [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

```
element(by.css('.zmdi-delete'));
element(by.css('button.btn-danger i'));
element(by.css('div.kebab i'));
element(by.css('div.card-convite>div.kebab>button>i'));
element(by.css('app-lista-convites-lote i.zmdi-delete'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to identify a unique CSS selector which is independent on where that item is in the DOM tree.

I would suggest to tell your CSS you want to target a locator with a tagName `button` that exists with a title `Remover convite` and has a type called `button`

That would create:

```
element(by.css('button[title="Remover convite"][type="button"]'));
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your solution. Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: There you go, as requested

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided to invoke `click()` on the button with *title* as **Remover convite** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css` # 1:

  ```
  element(by.css('div.card.card-convite.ng-star-inserted button.btn.btn-danger.btn-no-text[title="Remover convite"]'));
  ```
- `css` # 2:

  ```
  element(by.css("div.card.card-convite.ng-star-inserted button.btn.btn-danger.btn-no-text[title='Remover convite']>i.zmdi.zmdi-delete"));
  ```

**Note**: As the desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce [**`async/await`**](http://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await).

Answer (score 0):

have a go w/:

```
By.css('.kebab kebab-convite:first-child')
```

or also something like

```
let temp = await driver.findElement(By.css('.kebab kebab-convite'))
let button = await temp.findElement(By.css('button'))
button.click()
```